# Edit all files at depth 2

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'd like to perform an edit on every file named "game.ml" at depth 2 in a certain file hierarchy. My thought was to write

```
find myfiles -depth 2 -type f -name "game.ml" -exec sed -e 's/size = 5/size = 6/'  '{}' > game2.ml  \;
```

and then go back through the directory again and move all the "game2.ml" files back to game.ml, overwriting the originals. Really, what I want is sort of a "self-sed" operation, but I don't know of one.

The bad news is that the `find` command above doesn't put `game2.ml` into the directory where `game.ml` was, but into the directory from which the `find` was invoked.

Can someone suggest a way to fix this particular problem, or a better way to approach the whole task? Either would make me happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all of the files you want without `find`, with the shell pattern `myfiles/*/game.ml`.

You can edit them in-place more easily with `perl` than with `sed`:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/size = 5/size = 6/' myfiles/*/game.ml
```

The `-p` flag prints each input line to the output file (after expressions are evaluated). The `-i.bak` edits each file in place, saving the original with a `.bak` extension (so, `game.ml.bak`). The `-e` flag executes the following expression on each line of each file.

If you really want to do it with `sed`:

```
for f in myfiles/*/game.ml; do
    sed 's/size = 5/size = 6/' < "$f" > "$f".new && mv "$f".new "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

For POSIX you may use this `find`:

```
find myfiles -depth 2 -type f -name "game.ml" |
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   sed 's/size = 5/size = 6/' "$file" > game2.ml
done
```